# Variável não está exibindo o resultado esperado

Tags: c, variáveis, matemática

Na leitura da variável no final para exibir o valor, exibe um lixo, eis aqui o enunciado juntamente com o meu código.

> Faça um programa que receba a idade, a altura e o peso de cinco pessoas, calcule e mostre:
>
> - A quantidade de pessoas com idade superior a 50 anos;
> - A média das alturas das pessoas com idade entre 10 e 20 anos;
> - A porcentagem de pessoas com peso inferior a 40 kg entre 5 pessoas

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()

{
    int idade , cont50,md, espantalho, mdpeso, i;
    float peso, altura ;

    for (i = 1 ; i <3 ; i++)
    {



        printf ("\nDigite a sua idade :") ;
        scanf ("%d", &idade) ;

        printf ("Digite a sua altura :") ;
        scanf ("%f", &altura) ;

        printf ("Digite seu peso :") ;
        scanf ("%f", &peso) ;

        if ( idade > 50)
            cont50++ ;

        if((idade>=10) && (idade <=20))
            md +=altura/2 ;

        if(peso <40)
            espantalho++ ;

        mdpeso = (espantalho/2) *100 ;

    }

        printf ("\nO total de pessoas com idade superior a 50 e %d", cont50) ;
        printf ("\nA media das alturas de pessoas com idade entre 10 e 20 anos e %.1f", md) ;
        printf ("\nA porcentagem de pessoas com peso inferior a 40 kg e %f porcento", mdpeso) ;



return 0;

}
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Se ainda não o fez, veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando a melhor solução para você. Só pode aceitar apenas uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 6):

O maior problema é que alguns valores que aparentemente precisam ter parte decimal estarem sendo tratados como inteiros. Outro problema é a falta de inicialização das variáveis:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int idade = 0, cont50 = 0, espantalho = 0;
    float peso = 0.0, altura = 0.0, md = 0.0, mdpeso = 0.0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("\nDigite a sua idade :");
        scanf("%d", &idade);
        printf("Digite a sua altura :");
        scanf("%f", &altura);
        printf("Digite seu peso :");
        scanf("%f", &peso);
        if (idade > 50) cont50++;
        if (idade >= 10 && idade <= 20) md += altura / 2;
        if (peso < 40) espantalho++;
        mdpeso = (espantalho / 2.0) * 100; //força parte decimal necessária p/ porcentagem
    }
    printf("\nO total de pessoas com idade superior a 50 e %d", cont50);
    printf("\nA media das alturas de pessoas com idade entre 10 e 20 anos e %.1f", md);
    printf("\nA porcentagem de pessoas com peso inferior a 40 kg e %f porcento", mdpeso);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/QXdBDr). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ikeakobv-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Typing/Format.c).

Answer (score 0):

Inicie as variáveis com 0. Dependendo do valor ele pode não entrar em um dos if's.

Comment: Olá, a primeira condição foi resolvida, está mostrando quantas pessoas acima de 50 foram citadas, porém a média e porcentagem ainda esta dando 0, você acredita que a lógica do programa está certa para calcular as 2 ultimas condições?

Answer (score 0):

Você está atribuindo valores de variáveis do tipo float em variáveis do tipo int tente fazer o cast nessas situações.

Comment: Sua resposta pode estar certa, mas você pode dar uma melhorada nela. Tente explicar melhor o que está errado e como arrumar, isso já vai dar outra cara pra resposta. Aconselho você a dar uma olhada em [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde,

Creio que este problema esteja acontecendo por conta de as variáveis não serem inicializadas no código. Vai dar problema também as variáveis md, mdpeso, que devem ser float.

```
int idade = 0 , cont50 = 0, md = 0, espantalho = 0, mdpeso = 0, i = 0;
float peso = 0, altura = 0;
```

Comment: A parte da média das alturas, e porcentagem continuam dando zero, troquei as variáveis para float, e igualei a zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()

{
    int idade=0 , cont50=0, espantalho=0, i,idadevar =0;
    float peso=0.0, altura=0.0, mdpeso=0.0, md=0.0;

    for (i = 1 ; i <= 2 ; i++)
    {

        printf ("\nDigite a sua idade :") ;
        scanf ("%d", &idade) ;
        fflush(stdin);
        printf ("Digite a sua altura :") ;
        scanf ("%f", &altura) ;
        fflush(stdin);
        printf ("Digite seu peso :") ;
        scanf ("%f", &peso) ;
        fflush(stdin);
        if ( idade > 50)
            cont50++ ;

        if((idade>=10) && (idade <=20)){
           idadevar++;//Conta quantas pessoas tem idade entre 10 e 20 anos
           md += altura;
           }

        if(peso <40)
            espantalho++ ;



}
        mdpeso = (espantalho*100)/(i-1);//Número de pessoas com menos de 40kg vezes 100 dividido pelo total de pessoas
        md = md/idadevar;//Altura de todas as pessoas com 10 a 20 anos dividido pela quantidade de pessoas com 10 a 20 anos
        printf ("\nO total de pessoas com idade superior a 50 e %d", cont50) ;
        printf ("\nA media das alturas de pessoas com idade entre 10 e 20 anos e %.1f", md) ;
        printf ("\nA porcentagem de pessoas com peso inferior a 40 kg e %.1f porcento", mdpeso) ;



return 0;

}
```

Exercicio Corrigido